# Padrino with RVM gemsets: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Deprecation

Tags: ruby, rvm, activesupport, padrino, ruby-1.9.3

I'm getting an error trying to run an app, not even trying to do anything sophisticated either, just get the basic thing running... Just wondering if anyone can give me any pointers as to how to debug it. I suspect it might be to do with RVM gemsets, but I'm not sure...

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Deprecation
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/deprecation.rb:7:in `deprecate'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:44:in `<class:Module>'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module.rb:8:in `require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/lib/padrino-core/support_lite.rb:13:in `require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/lib/padrino-core/support_lite.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/lib/padrino-core.rb:2:in `require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/padrino-core-0.9.21/lib/padrino-core.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/padrino-0.9.21/lib/padrino.rb:2:in `require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@marathon_site/gems/padrino-0.9.21/lib/padrino.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
~/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `require'
~/Documents/Projects/MarathonSite/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have activesupport 3.2.1 listed in the gemset with my project, so I'm not entirely sure why it's complaining. Any pointers as to what's going on would be appreciated, so I can debug this kind of thing in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a gem clashing.

1. Update padrino to latest version 0.10.5 (or 0.10.6.c)

   gem install padrino --pre
2. Try using a stable version of bundler

   gem uninstall bundler -a; gem install bundler
3. Edit gemfile of your project and point to padrino 0.10.5 or 0.10.6.c

Comment: Thanks, adding the specific version number of Padrino to the Gemfile seemed to solve it. Out of interest, how did you know it was a Gem clashing? What was actually occurring that caused this error?

Comment: Because padrino 0.10.5 depends from ActiveSupport 3.1 and your stacktrace show the 3.2. I don't know what caused the problem, maybe bundler --pre or rvm gemset.